# How to grep, then cut from a delimited column file?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, cut

I have a file with multiple rows, each row delimited with `|` into multiple columns.
I can grep for a certain row, and I can cut for a certain column, but I can't figure out how to do both.

```
grep '^1001' customer
```

grabs rows starting with 1001, from a file named customer

```
cut -d "|" -f 3 customer
```

cuts column 3 from all the rows in customer file.

So....

```
grep '^1001' customer | cut -d "|" -f 3 customer
```

Comment: If you wanted rows starting with 1001, add a `^` to your grep command as such: `grep "^1001"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply omit the filename when you call `cut` and it'll use the output of `grep` as its input:

```
grep 1001 customer | cut -d "|" -f 3
```

It is also worth noting that `grep 1001` doesn't grab rows starting with 1001; it grabs rows *containing* 1001.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thanks for the side not too. That was pretty important and helpful

Answer (score 4):

Better use ask for this task like this **and avoid multiple commands with pipe**:

```
awk -F "|" '$1==1001{print $3}' customer
```

Comment: +1 however field comparison would be better here `awk -F "|" '$1==1001{print $3}' customer`

Comment: @sudo_O Thanks I edited my answer. I had it as `/1001/` because initially OP's problem just stated that he wanted to match this string in the whole line.